# Django with Unicorn losing thread local storage during requst

Tags: python, django, multithreading, gunicorn

I've set up a request-scope cache using middleware and tried to set it to be available from anywhere using threading.local() variable. However, sometimes long requests processes drop with the following error:

```
  File "label.py", line 29, in get_from_request_cache
    label = cache.labels[url]
AttributeError: '_thread._local' object has no attribute 'labels'
```

However, some of the items get processed correctly, and they all depend on existence of that cache.

The cache object is initialized once and is cleared at the end of the request using the following middleware:

**request_cache.py**

```
import threading

_request_cache = threading.local()

def get_request_cache():
    return _request_cache

class RequestCacheMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        global _request_cache
        response = self.get_response(request)
        _request_cache.__dict__.clear()

        return response

    def process_exception(self, request, exception):
        _request_cache.__dict__.clear()
        return None
```

And the only code that accesses the cache object directly is this part:

**label.py**

```
import django.db.models

from request_cache import get_request_cache
from base import Model


class Label(Model):
    **model fields**

    @staticmethod
    def create_for_request_cache(urls):
        cache = get_request_cache()
        urls = set(urls)
        if not hasattr(cache, 'labels'):
            cache.labels = {}
        new_urls = urls.symmetric_difference(set(cache.labels.keys()))
        entries = [Label(url=url) for url in new_urls]
        if entries:
            Label.objects.bulk_create(entries)
            for entry in entries:
                cache.labels[entry.url] = entry

    @staticmethod
    def get_from_request_cache(url):
        cache = get_request_cache()
        label = cache.labels[url]
        return label
```

The request that crashes is split into batches in code, and before each batch, new unique urls are taken and added to the cache with the following code, and that's where the process crashes:

**fill_labels.py**

```
class LabelView(django.views.generic.base.View):
    def _fill_labels_batch(items_batch):
        VersionLabel.create_for_request_cache([item.get('url', '') for item in items_batch])

        for item in items_batch:
            **process items** - CRASHES HERE

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, subcategory):
        item_batches = **split items into batches**
        for item_batch in item_batches:
            _fill_labels_batch(item_batch)
```

If I correctly understand the way Django and Gunicorn work, the thread local object should be local to either a thread if there has been no monkey patching, or to a greenlet if Gunicorn does monkey patching internally, and Django uses the same thread for the entire duration of the request, which means that thread local storage should not change mid-request in either of those cases. However, it's possible to have several requests being processed at the same time and each request can have input data of around 200MB and the time it takes to process the request can be several hours - the last crash happened after 4 hours of processing.

What could be the reason behind the request process losing this cache? If it wasn't created at all, the request would crash much faster, and I can't think of a reason for Django to change or lose `threading.local()` object mid-request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding explicit `monkey.patch_all()` call somehow fixed the issue. The root of the problem has remained unknown.